# Autowire annotation driven bean into bean specified in Java config with constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Let's say I have a service bean that's initialised by component-scanning:

```
@Service
public class MyService { ... }
```

I have a bean `A` configured in my Java application config, which depends on another bean `B` also defined in the Java config, which in turn depends on `Service` using constructor injection. I can use autowiring in the bean factory for `A` and pass it on to `B`:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public A a(MyService service) {
    return new A(b(service));
}

@Bean
public B b(MyService service) {
     return new B(service);
}
```

However, this doesn't feel very clean to me. `a()` shouldn't be concerned with `MyService`. But if I'm to call `new B(service)` I need to get a service into `b()` somehow, and if that's a method parameter, `a()` needs to put something in there.

I have tried:

```
 @Autowired private MyService service;

@Autowired
public A a() {
    return new A(b());
}

@Bean
public B b() {
    return new B(service);
}
```

But this injects `null` into `new B(...)` - evidently Spring populates the field after calling `b()`.

I've also tried:

```
 public B b() {
     return new B(context.getBean(MyService.class));
 }
```

... this results in a `BeanInstantiationException` related to a circular reference.

How can I get the `MyService` bean into `b()`'s `new B(...)` directly?

---

Update: the above is a simplification of what I actually want to do.

The real scenario is that I have a bunch of `Action` beans which use shared `DataService` bean to access data. Then I have a `CompositeAction` class which contains references to several `Action` objects and invokes the appropriate one depending on runtime criteria.

I want to configure two beans of type `CompositeAction`, each with its own hand-configured set of delegate `Action` beans. But I would like the `Action` beans to be autowired with the `DataService`, by constructor injection.

```
CompositeAction ----> Action ---\
             |                   \
              \-----> Action ---\ \
                                   ---->   DataService
CompositeAction ----> Action ---/ /
             |                   /
             \------> Action ---/
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
@Bean
public A a(B b) {
    return new A(b);
}

@Bean
public B b(MyService service) {
    return new B(service);
}
```

Comment: Because I want to explicitly configure which `B` gets injected into `a`.  I don't want it auto-wiring into A.

Comment: So you want `B` bean instance configured for the application but another `B` instance configured for bean `A`? If that's so, how about another B definition with some `@Qualifier`?. Or maybe have a basic `B` definition with a prototype scope and further customize it after injection?

Comment: I added some more about what I want to achieve, in the question.

Comment: I see, so how about making `Action` bean prototype scoped and autowiring instances of it into `CompositeAction`? That way `CompositeAction` definition does not handle `Action` instances creation but still gets distinct ones.